# Is the scientific calculator no longer available from control center as accessed from the lock screen?

Tags: ios, control-center, lockscreen

The calculator app: woot! Extra joy to find out what happens when you rotate the phone 90°… double woot!

Yet more joy to find the calculator can be accessed from the lock screen by placing it in Control Center. (Triple woot!)

Until a year or so ago I could access the scientific calculator from the lock screen by rotating the phone. But in iOS 15 (iPhone SE 1st gen) and iOS 16 (iPhone SE 2nd gen), this no longer works.

**Is there some way to re-enable the scientific calculator as accessed from the Control Center *in the lock screen*?**

Answer (score 1):

Rotation of the calculator does not appear to be possible when accessed while the phone is locked.

If you unlock the phone (say, via Face ID) you can then use the calculator shortcut and it can rotate. There is no need to swipe to the home screen first in this scenario.